# How should we store DateTimes in OrientDB from Scala/Play?

Tags: scala, datetime, playframework, jodatime, orientdb

We need to represent DateTimes in our Scala 2.10 Play 2.2 project, and these values must be stored in OrientDB. Which type should we use to represent DateTime values, in general and towards OrientDB?

We've looked at the Joda Time Scala wrapper [nscala-time](https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time), would this be a good choice? I guess it would have to be converted to a standard Java type which OrientDB can store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrientDB supports date and datetime types. It stores both as long (unix time), so in order to use Joda with OrientDB you could convert Joda Time into longs.